# Azure ADF Nasa Image to SQL Server

Tags: oracle-adf

I have been banging my head against a wall for the past week. Hoping you can help. I am trying to write the contents of an image file I get from a URL to a SQL Server table. I am getting the NASA image of the day that holds in the URL a link to an image file (hard coded for this test https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2305/virgoCL1024.jpg). I use the Web activity to get the image and insert the value in a table with a varbinary(max) data type. It writes the information but when I try to extract the data from the table (using C# it says invalid image. Or the be exact 'Parameter is invalid' when I use Image.FromStream).

I have tried to convert the output from the Web activity to base64 and then write to SQL Server varchar(max) or nvarchar(max). Then decode in C#, but no joy. What is strange is the output from the Web activity if I put it in an azure variable doesn't match the hexdump of the raw image file (saved the image to my pc). Has the Web activity already converted the output in some format. Before I get to it. Any help would be most appreciated. Cheers